# how do i save a rtf file using php?

Tags: php, file, save, rtf

```
$rtf=<<<RTF
    {\rtf1
    \b [TITLE] \b0\par
    \b [MESSAGE] \b0\par
    }
RTF;

$rtf = str_replace('[TITLE]',$valueTitle,$rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[MESSAGE]',$valueMessage,$rtf);
```

After I have finished editing a rtf file in php like above, how do i save it with a new file name in a specific location for people to download?

Comment: take a look at fwrite: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save it with `file_put_contents()` and simply offer the link to download, with the appropriate headers.

```
// $rtf holds your complete file data
file_put_contents('/path/to/outfile.rtf', $rtf);
```

Then you can either simply give them the direct download, or serve it with the right headers like this, useful if you need additional processing or access protection or something...

```
header("Content-type: application/rtf");
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/outfile.rtf");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

found my old file where I had already done this, so this is the exact working code that I am using right now.

```
$rtf= file_get_contents('result.rtf');

$rtf = str_replace('[nickname]', $nickname, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[secretWord]', $secretWord, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[hoursInADay]', $hoursInADay, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[hobby]', $hobby, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[hobbyYears]', $hobbyYears, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[hobbyAlphabet]', $hobbyAlphabet, $rtf);
$rtf = str_replace('[jokeFact]', $jokeFact, $rtf);

header('Content-type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=survey_result.rtf');
echo $rtf;
die();
```